# In a regex, how do I ensure that if I find one particular character, I should also find another character as well in the string?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have to create a regex which has a condition which says that if I encounter a certain special character, I should also find another special character.
For example, if I find the character `{` in my string, that particular string would be considered a valid string only if it also has `}` in it. I have tried my hands on lookarounds, but I am still unable to figure it out with infinite-width lookarounds.

Valid strings:

> example{}
>   example{example}
>   example}example{

Invalid strings:

> example{example
>   example}example

Comment: As long as these special characters are not nested, a regex for matching these can be written but not if they are nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex which does just what is asked:

```
^[^{}\n]*$|^(?=[^{\n]*\{)(?=[^}\n]*\}).*
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Y53ysw/2)

matches

- either a line which doesn't contain `{` or `}`
- or a line that contains at least one `{` and at least one `}`